# Multiple table optimized oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I know every question on queries can be different so I still hope this was not answered earlier.
I am after a optimized Oracle sql query that will scan multiple tables.

Let me tell you my requirements :

We have a UNIQUEREFERENCE table where we insert entitykey (of 3 main entities we have say A,B and C) in combination of hash of reference fields (Varchar) as columns are as below :

```
UNIQUEREFERENCEKEY REFERENCENAME REFERENCE IDENTIFIER1 IDENTIFIER2 SEQUENCE ORIGINALAKEY ORIGINALBKEY  ORIGINALCKEY ORIGINALENTITYTYPE ORIGINALDISPLAYENTITYID REFERENCETIME ID3
```

Now I have to write a query that shouldn't bring any row from the above table making sure that none of the 3 entities have status as "Rejected" or "Cancelled". If there is some row returned then we treat it as duplicate of A or B or C, based upon what was ORIGINALENTITYTYPE.

If nothing is returned then we insert new reference in this table and process continues.

My attempt so far :

```
 select
            REFERENCENAME as referenceName,
            REFERENCE as reference,
            IDENTIFIER1 as Identifier1,
            IDENTIFIER2 as Identifier2,
            max(SEQUENCE) as maxSequence,
            count(1) as totalCount,
            min(ORIGINALDISPLAYENTITYID) keep (dense_rank first order by sequence ) as firstDisplayId,
            min(ID3) keep (dense_rank first order by sequence ) as firstId3,
            min(case
                    when 'com.example.domain.A' = :checkEntityName and ORIGINALENTITYTYPE = :checkEntityName and ORIGINALAKEY = :checkEntityKey
                        then ORIGINALAKEY
                    when 'com.example.domain.B' = :checkEntityName and ORIGINALENTITYTYPE = :checkEntityName and ORIGINALBKEY = :checkEntityKey
                        then ORIGINALBKEY
                    when 'com.example.domain.C' = :checkEntityName and ORIGINALENTITYTYPE = :checkEntityName and ORIGINALCKEY = :checkEntityKey
                        then ORIGINALCKEY
                    else null
                end) as entityKey
        from UNIQUEREFERENCE
        where REFERENCENAME = :referenceName
            and REFERENCE = :reference
            and NVL(IDENTIFIER2, 'N/A') = NVL(:Identifier2, 'N/A')
            and NVL(IDENTIFIER1, 'N/A') = NVL(:Identifier1, 'N/A')
        group by REFERENCENAME, REFERENCE, IDENTIFIER1, IDENTIFIER2
```

As you can see the parameters checkEntityName and checkEntityKey will be replaced at runtime in this generic query for all 3 entities.

Now I just have to make a join on 3 entityKey from entity table to make sure we don't consider those entities (A,B and C) whose status in ("Rejected", "Cancelled") and I cannot come up with a perfect optimized query so far.

Any help would be really appreciated or any better way to solve this in a single sql query.

Thanks.

Update : Adding sample data as requested.

UniqueReference table

```
1 TEST1 XYZ1234 null ABCD SEQ12345 1231 null null com.example.domain.A null  
2 TEST2 XYZ4567 null ABCD SEQ12346 null 2341 null com.example.domain.B null  
3 TEST3 XYZ8910 null ABCD SEQ12347 null null 5671 com.example.domain.C null
```

And then entity table A

```
s.no  reference   status  
1     XYZ1234     Rejected  
2     XYZ4561     Processed  
3     XYZ7891     Cancelled
```

And then entity table B

```
s.no  reference   status  
1     XYZ4567     Processed
2     XYZ6561     Processed  
3     XYZ8891     Cancelled
```

And then entity table C

```
s.no  reference   status  
1     XYZ8910     Cancelled  
2     XYZ8562     Processed  
3     XYZ1789     Cancelled
```

From above uniquereference data I don;t expect row 1 or 3 to be returned in case entityType is A or C, because corresponding reference (XYZ1234,XYZ8910) for A and C has status Rejected/Cancelled respectively. 
While row 2 of uniquereference will be returned as entity B is not Rejected or Cancelled and hence the reference cannot be re-used and it will be duplicate for this use-case.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Updated on your request, let me know if it makes it bit clear.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't completely clear on some of the details for your usage, but this approach may help if I'm understanding correctly:

```
SELECT UR.reference
     , UR.fieldA
     , UR.fieldB
     , UR.fieldN
     , COUNT(EntityA.sno) +
       COUNT(EntityB.sno) +
       COUNT(EntityC.sno) as subrecords
FROM UniqueReference UR
LEFT JOIN EntityA A
    ON UR.reference = A.reference
    AND A.status = 'PROCESSED'
LEFT JOIN EntityB B
    ON UR.reference = B.reference
    AND B.status = 'PROCESSED'
LEFT JOIN EntityC C
    ON UR.reference = C.reference
    AND C.status = 'PROCESSED'
GROUP BY UR.reference
HAVING subrecords > 0
-- this may need to be: HAVING COUNT(EntityA.sno) + COUNT(EntityB.sno) + COUNT(EntityC.sno) > 0
```